# Thread WaitHandle on a Single Thread

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading, parallel-processing

My code is

```
public static void Invoke(Action[] Actions)
{
    Thread[] threadArray = new Thread[Actions.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < Actions.Length; i++)
    {
        threadArray[i] = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Actions[i].Invoke();
        });
        threadArray[i].Start();
    }
}

public static void WaitAll()
{

}

public static void WaitAny()
{

}
```

I want to wait for all threads to complete, and also get notification when any thread completes,

like `WaitAny`, `WaitAll`

But waithandles can be used on threadpools only, could not find any examples for use on single thread.

My app requires a lot of threads, hundreds of them, theadpool has max thread limit, rest tasks are queued.

How do I manage that??

**UPDATE:** here is the code, please let me know if better code possible.

```
public class ParallelV2
{
    static int waitcount = 0;
    static WaitHandle[] waitHandles;

    public static void Invoke(Action[] Actions)
    {
        waitcount = Actions.Length;

        Thread[] threadArray = new Thread[Actions.Length];
        waitHandles = new WaitHandle[Actions.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < Actions.Length; i++)
        {
            var count = i;

            waitHandles[count] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            threadArray[count] = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Actions[count].Invoke();
                ((AutoResetEvent)waitHandles[count]).Set();
            });

            threadArray[count].Start();
        }
    }

    public static void WaitAll()
    {
        while (waitcount > 0)
        {
            WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles);
            waitcount--;
        }
    }

    public static void WaitAny()
    {
        WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles);
    }
}
```

Comment: But you're essentially making a thread pool here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example below, I had three threads that I needed to track.  Each thread, when it was done would set its corresponding handle.

Declare it like this:

```
private WaitHandle[] waithandles;  // see comment on static below
```

Create it like this:

```
waitcount = 3;
waithandles = new WaitHandle[3] { new AutoResetEvent(false), new AutoResetEvent(false), new AutoResetEvent(false) };
```

In the thread, when its finished,set it like this:

```
((AutoResetEvent)waithandles[i]).Set();
```

(Actually, thats over-simplified, but it will work if you make the waithandle static.  What I actually did was have the thread perform a callback at the end of its life to signal the waithandle)

In the main thread, check it like this.  When the waitcount reached zero, I knew all threads had completed

```
while (waitcount > 0)
{
    WaitHandle.WaitAny(waithandles, 30000);
    waitcount--;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can wait for a thread `myThread` to complete with `myThread.Join()`.